# Как перевести кодировку, чтобы скрипт ее распознал?

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

phpMyAdmin понимает запросы, если они приходят с данными, например, как 'Eaai', а в скрипте это 'Иван'.

```
echo $arr[$i]; // в Chrome выводится Иван
$s = "SELECT SUM(`square`)  FROM `reports` WHERE `username` = '".$arr[$i]."';"; // а сюда должно попасть 'Eaai', чтобы все выполнилось
```

Как перевести кодировку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так у вас данные не в cp1251. Посмотрите сами: [декодер](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/) - детектирует Eaai как 7-bit ASCII → ISO-8859-5 + CP1251 → ISO-8859-5

Посмотрите, что выведет `mysql status;` у вас скорее всего не правильно настроен mysql сервер. Хотя может быть не в той кодировке изначально сохранён файл, сервер ответ отдаёт не в той кодировке...

Ещё вот это попробуйте - [`ob_iconv_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-iconv-handler.php).

Comment: смотрите в корень вопроса - данные пришли не в той кодировке, нечего пенять на мускул, надо трениться иконвом на приходе

Comment: В помощь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/107945/

Comment: в какой кодировке у вас бд ?

Comment: utf-8 unicode ci

Comment: Сохраните документ (скрипт) в UTF-8 и, по идеи, проблема будет решена.

Comment: сохранила, но в браузер выводится кракозябрами все..и не выполняется опять..

Comment: последняя версия, попробуйте еще это: mb_convert_encoding

Comment: не знаю уже что делать..
у меня с кодировкой были проблемы на странице с логином

но я сделала $Login1 = mb_convert_encoding($Login, "CP1251", "UTF-8"); и эту переменную в запрос, все нормально выпоняется..
но только здесь Логин пользователь вводит в браузере,
 а что сейчас пытаюсь сделать - по идее переменная ;\$arr1 была получена из БД запросом..но с ней такие преобразования не получаютсчя((

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `iconv`.

Comment: попыталась так

echo $arr[$i];
        $mes = iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i]); 
        $s = "SELECT SUM(`square`)  FROM `reports` WHERE `username` = '$mes';";

но тоже не выполнился запрос..(

Comment: не выполнился - какая вышла ошибка ? или просто небыло переконвертации ?

Comment: конвертация выполнилась..запрос превратился в 

SELECT SUM(`square`) FROM `reports` WHERE `username` = 'РРІР°РЅ';

но не выполняется..